# How can I add a thin user Icon in my website?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I want to add a thin user icon to my website and I used font awesome.

It shows a box error.

```
<i class="fa-thin fa-user"></i>
```

The class thin `fa-thin` is not working. If I use `fa-user` it comes with a solid user icon. How can I make `fa-thin` work? Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. The problem is not apparent from what you've shown us.

Comment: Note that [`fa-user fa-thin`](https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/user?s=thin&f=classic) is a Pro (paid) collection icon: "To use the thin style of “user“, you'll need a subscription to a Pro-level plan or a perpetual Pro license that includes the specific version of Font Awesome in which this icon (or style) was released."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<i class="fa-thin fa-user"></i>`, if you are using the latest version of font-awesome.

Comment: If you're using the lates _Pro_ (paid) version.